# HtmlCanvasElement toDataURL does not seem to work after drawing on the canvas with WebGL

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl

I have been following along the tutorials from MDN on WebGL and now I wanted to export the image drawn from the canvas using `toDataURL` and setting the source for an `<img>` tag. However generating the data url only ever seems to be generating a transparent image.

I basically used the code given in the tutorial, [link](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/tree/gh-pages/tutorial/sample5) and augmented the `index.html` like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WebGL Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webgl.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="glcanvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
    <button id="take">SNAP</button>
    <img id="screenshot" src="" width="640" height="480">
  </body>

  <script src="gl-matrix.js"></script>
  <script src="webgl-demo.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    take.onclick = () => {
        const dataUrl = glcanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log(dataUrl);
        screenshot.src = dataUrl;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this does not work?

Comment: `take.onclick = ...`/`screenshot.src = ...` - This will most likely work but you should not rely on it, as this is no specified behavior but some nutty Microsoft stuff -> [Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: yeah, but this is just for testing purposes, so no worries

Comment: You might find [these tutorials useful](https://webglfundamentals.org)